# PGSync with aws elasticsearch: index not found

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to sync my Postgres database with Aws Elasticsearch using [PGSync](https://pgsync.com/env-vars/)
I have defined a simple schema:

```
    [
  {
    "database": "tenancyportal",
    "index": "properties",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "table": "properties",
        "schema": "public",
        "columns": ["id", "address"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But when I am trying to bootstrap the database using

> bootstrap --config schema.json

I get the following error:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404,
> 'index_not_found_exception', 'no such index [:9200]', :9200,
> index_or_alias)

In the below screenshot, you will be able to see the GET URL for elasticsearch is completely wrong, I am not able to understand what config is causing it to be formed like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your AWS Elasticsearch URL is not constructed properly. This was adressed in a recent update to PGSync. Can you pull the latest [master](https://github.com/toluaina/pgsync) branch and try this again.

Comment: I am not able to connect aws elasticsearch by using 2.1.9 from pgsync. it is throwing 401 (Unauthorized error)
`Undecodable raw error response from server: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
and
`Elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthenticationException: AuthenticationException(401, 'Unauthorized')`

Comment: @taina I tried but again the URL is not correctly formed, this is the formed URL ``elasticsearch: GET https://search-elastic-XXX.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:9200/`` why its adding the port number in the end ? this is causing the request to be timed out

Comment: The default port is 9200. You can change it to 443 by setting the env var `ELASTICSEARCH_PORT`